# Xamarin App crashes after testFlight release before my code runs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, testflight, crash-reports, visual-studio-app-center

Hello and thank you for reading.

This is my first time publishing an ios application and I am using Xamarin to publish my app to both Android and iOS (as requested by the client ).

Now the application deploys and works correctly when I run it via visual studio/Rider but when I push it to testflight (via azure pipeline and microsoft App Center) I get the following Crash report:
 [link to crashreport](https://pastebin.com/X3edzfub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oke so after some triel and error I have found the problem:
Apparently in Xamarin if you use EFCore then there is the possibility of mTouch to skip the reflections used by it
more info (and my saving grace) was found here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin#explore-the-code](https://oke%20so%20after%20some%20triel%20and%20error%20I%20have%20found%20the%20problem:%20Apparently%20in%20Xamarin%20if%20you%20use%20EFCore%20then%20there%20is%20the%20possibility%20of%20mlink%20to%20stril%20the%20reflections%20used%20by%20it%20more%20info%20(and%20my%20saving%20grace)%20was%20found%20here:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin#explore-the-code)